# Как скачать все фото из альбома? Python, PyTelegramBotApi

Tags: python, telebot

Когда пользователь отправляет фото по отдельности они скачиваются без проблем, а если 2 или больше фото вместе, то скачивается одно фото. Как мне скачать все фото из альбома?
Вот код:

```
bot.message_handler(content_types=["photo"])
def photo(message):
    username = message.from_user.username

    if not os.path.exists(username):
        try:
            os.mkdir(username)
        except FileExistsError:
            pass

    raw = message.photo[2].file_id

    if len(photos[username]) == 1:
        user_data[username]["questions"].pop(0)
        send_message(message.chat.id, user_data[username]["questions"][0])
    elif len(photos[username]) == 2:
        user_data[username]["questions"].pop(0)
    
    path = f"{username}/{len(photos[username]) + 1}.jpg"

    file_info = bot.get_file(raw)
    downloaded_file = bot.download_file(file_info.file_path)

    # Save photo
    with open(path, "wb") as new_file:
        new_file.write(downloaded_file)
        photos[username].append(path)
```

Comment: Попробуйте использовать `threaded=False` при создании экземпляра бота: `bot = TeleBot(token, threaded=False)` и сообщите поведение. Скорее всего проблема в том, что в коде не потокобезопасно добавляются пути к фото в список.

Comment: Спасибо, мне это помогло)

Comment: это не очень хорошее решение проблемы, попробуйте почитать про потоки и блокировки в Python, например про модуль threading